# Dynamically create buttons with onclick function

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I want to dynamically create buttons for each cell in a table, which works fine. The problem is that i now want to assign them server side click events, like this:

```
Button b = new Button();
b.Text = "Delete";
b.CssClass = "btnDelete";
b.Click += new EventHandler(this.deletePictures_Click);
```

While this would be my deletePictures_Click:

```
private void deletePictures_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    test.Text = "hi";
}
```

But it won't fire. I did quite some research but couldn't find anything that helped me, yet. Do you guys know what's wrong?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

Here's the rendered HTML

```
<td class="resultCell">
<img class="resultpicture" src="photos/DSC_101.jpg">
<input name="ctl00$cphContentBox$ctl02" value="Delete" class="btnDelete" type="submit"></td>
```

**Edit:**

I saved all the buttons in a List and then in the Session. In the OnInit I iterated the List, assigning the Button.OnClientClick to each of them. But the event still won't fire! Here's the code:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);
    if (Session["buttons"] != null)
    {
        buttons = (List<Button>)Session["buttons"];
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Count; i++)
        {
            buttons[i].OnClientClick += new EventHandler(deletePictures_Click);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share what's the rendered HTML of this?

Comment: I edited my post to show you.

Comment: I assume you don't add those buttons to page after postback. And use `OnClick` instead of `OnClientClick`.

Answer (score 0):

The easy idea is to use a `grid-view` instead a table.

In the above problem you need to recreate you element on `pre_init` evetn.
Here is a good link
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dbc12b8c-8796-4800-a45f-57f24b8ef72b/dynamically-created-button-event-is-not-working

Comment: I saved all the buttons in a List<Button> and then in the Session. In the OnInit I iterated the List<String>, assigning the Button.OnClientClick to each of them. But the event still won't fire!
I will edit the code in my post to show you what exactly I did.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create an array of objects (i think a collection of them), then cycle them with a foreach construct

at school i did it in java, printing buttons in a table with foreach and collections